# How can I fade the changes when using the toggleClass() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is what I have tried. The class toggles, but does not fade.

```
function showNav(){
            $("div.divNav").toggleClass("showNav");
            $("div.divNav").fadeToggle("slow");
        }
```

Is it possible to use CSS transitions instead?

Comment: Yes, use css transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try toggling the fade first, then toggle off the class:

```js
function showNav() {
  $("div.divNav").fadeToggle("slow");
  $("div.divNav").toggleClass("showNav");
}
setTimeout(function() {
  showNav();
}, 300);
```

```css
.divNav {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divNav">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even think of that. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `fadeToggle("slow");`should work... But you can try [Css3-transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Take a look in this example:

```css
.divNav {
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.divNav:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="divNav">
</div>
```